# Put the search results at the top of the screen in vi

Tags: vim, vi

After each `n` command to search for the next match I would like *vi* to automatically position the line at the top of the screen.

Comment: "vi" or "vim" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `zt` command will redraw vim so that the current line is at the top of the screen. From [`:h zt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#z%3CCR%3E):

```
                            *z<CR>*
z<CR>           Redraw, line [count] at top of window (default
            cursor line).  Put cursor at first non-blank in the
            line.

                            *zt*
zt          Like "z<CR>", but leave the cursor in the same
            column.  {not in Vi}
```

So you can accomplish this with the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap n nzt
nnoremap N Nzt
xnoremap n nzt
xnoremap N Nzt
```

Although personally, I prefer leaving it in the middle, so I have the following instead:

```
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
```

Comment: Thank you - this is very useful for slogging through valgrind output as the stuff that precedes the search is of no interest.

Answer (score 5):

Use `:set so=999`

Using this, cursor will always be at middle line. So after each `n` command to search for the next match vim automatically position the cursor at middle line of the screen.

This is advantageous as we can see the context around the search.

For more details see `:help scrolloff`